# In how many ways can you select a group of $2$ women and $3$ men, and a single president for the group selected out of its members?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $8$ women and $15$ men in class. The instructor must select $5$ to be on a committee.  In how many ways can you select a group of $2$ women and $3$ men, and a single president for the group selected out of its members?

Is this a proper answer? $^{8}C_{2} \times ^{15}C_{3} \times ^{5}C_{1}$

Comment: Add you attempts to your question, thank you.

Comment: The president would be one of those chosen $5$ people?

Comment: Your last edit removed information necessary to answer the question.  The entire question should be posed in the body of the question.  Also, you should explain your reasoning, which helps readers detect any errors you may have made.

Answer (score 3):

(2 out of 8)*(3 out of 15)*(1 out of 5) = 28x455x5 = 63700

Answer (score 2):

We have $8$ women and we want to select $2$ of them to be part of the committee. That can be done with combinations (since selecting the woman $A$ and the woman $B$ is the same as selecting the woman $B$ and the woman $A$, the order is irrelevant). So this event can happen in $^{8}C_{2} = 28$ ways.

The same reasoning can be extended for the men. So we have $^{15}C_{3} = 455$ distinct ways of selecting $3$ men.

Out of these $5$ people, we want to select a president, so there is $5$ ways of doing that election.

By the product rule, we have that there are $28 \times 455 \times 5 = 63700$ distinct ways of picking these people.